# Class not found exception in PHP from composer

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am trying to include a package from composer, but I am receiving a **class not found** error.

I have tried the below possibilities.

```
$supermeteor = new \Supermeteor\Supermeteor('XXXXXXXX');
```

and

```
use Supermeteor\Supermeteor;
$supermeteor = new Supermeteor('xxxxxxxx');
```

Packages composer.json:

```
"psr-4": {
     "Supermeteor\\": ""
}
```

Packages namespace :

```
namespace Supermeteor;
```

Packages class name :

```
class Supermeteor() {}
```

Error message

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Supermeteor\Supermeteor' not found in
>   C:\path\to\my\file.php:16

Comment: What does your file structure look like? Where is the Supermeteor class file in relation to your composer.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your package locally, and it seems to work fine for me using the same code as you provided in your question. This is how I tested it.

## 1. Create a new project

Create a new directory on your computer.

## 2. Add the package to a new project using Composer

Locate your new directory on the command line and add the package to your projects autoloader by running the below composer command.

```
composer require supermeteor/sdk-php
```

## 3. Use the package

Create an index.php file in the same directory as your `composer.json` and add the below code.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Supermeteor\Supermeteor;

$supermeteor = new Supermeteor("xxx");
```

## 4. Test the results

In the terminal window start a new php server to serve your project.

```
php -S localhost:8089
```

Now access the site via your browser at http://localhost:8089.

Comment: thanks its worked.
I forgot to include require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
this line.